# Flutter: RaisedButton expand and shrink, but also text that shrinks and expands

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Dear Flutter community,

I have a row with one RaisedButton on the right and one RaisedButton on the left. Both RaisedButtons do have Text inside and the Text can be of different length (only one word no sentences). I always want the RaisedButton to be as small as possible so that the Text just fits the RaisedButton. So the size of the RaisedButton is flexible. Next to that, I also do not want the RaisedButton to be too wide (height is fixed as well), because this is ugly and can cause a pixeloverflow. So this means that once the limit of the size of the RaisedButton is reached, the fontSize of the text should shrink. (Note I first want the button to expand and if this is not enough, I want the text to shrink, not the other way around).
You can find some code below:

```
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () …
                        color: App.focusColor,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: App.primaryColor),
                        ),
                        child: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                            maxHeight: 20,
                            minHeight: 20,
                          ),
                          child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                            child: Text(
                                …),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () …
                        color: App.focusColor,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: App.primaryColor),
                        ),
                        child: ConstrainedBox(
                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                    minWidth:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                                    maxWidth:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            0.35,
                                    maxHeight: 20,
                                    minHeight: 20,
                                  ),
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                        …,
                                    maxFontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

[image: row with two raisedButtons but textSize is not equal]

The problem this code has, is that the fontSize is not equal for both RaisedButtons. How can I make sure that the fontSize is equal, but that the RaisedButtons still can change wide (I want that the RaisedButtons do have different sizes if the textlength is not equal)?

In addition to that If I have multiple rows with two RaisedButtons, I want that all the fontSizes are always equal.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: please cehck the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below answer. No need to use FittedBox.

```
final text = 'It is a long title for button';

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      color: App.focusColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: App.primaryColor),
      ),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
        ),
        child: Text(text.length > 10 ? '${text.substring(0, 10)}...' : text),
      ),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      color: App.focusColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: App.primaryColor),
      ),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
        ),
        child: Text("abcaaa"),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: But now if the text is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", I will get a Pixeloverflow, so I need to make the text smaller...

Comment: You mentioned that, you need text same size, it becomes small, and you do not need it

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a maxHeight as well like: maxHeight: 20. This means that I can only have one line of text. I update the code above.

Comment: So it means that the "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" will only be displayed partly. I want the text to shrink. An the text of the other raisedbutton should then also shrink accordingly.

Comment: Ok, its also possible, how many letter you want to show

Comment: Is it come from any other declared string?

Comment: @ArnoudWellens, check the answer i edited, please upvote and accept if it fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FittedBox` to manage text based on height or width of the `RaisedButton`.
so simplly wrap your text in a `FittedBox`

```
BoxConstraints(
   /* max height and other attribute
   ... 
   */
   child: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.fitWidth, child: Text('MUONEWOrdTEXT'),),
  ),
```